# Синхронизация профиля StackExchange с данными ru.stackoverflow.com

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

В моем [профиле StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/users/2253426/andreycha) сейчас два [аккаунта](http://stackexchange.com/users/2253426/andreycha?tab=accounts). При этом в статистике (Top Answers и количество ответов в сообществе "StackOverflow на русском") проигнорированы ответы, которые были опубликованы еще на ХэшКоде. Отображаются только данные непосредственно с ru.stackoverflow.com, начиная с 1 апреля. Это ошибка, так задумано или просто еще не все данные синхронизировались?

**UPD.** Вопрос с объединением профилей не имеет ничего общего. Здесь проблема в неактуальной статистике, отображаемой в профиле StackExchange.

**UPD2.** Починилось.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Объединиение профилей SO и HC](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/9/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-so-%d0%b8-hc)

Comment: да, есть такая ошибка, видимо статы почему-то не обновились

Comment: Ошибка ушла, статистика обновилась. Вопрос можно закрыть.